# Determine the support of an infinite divisible probability measure on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, levy-processes

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb R$ and $$\mathcal L_\mu(t):=\int e^{-tx}\:\mu({\rm d}x)\;\;\;\text{for }t\in\mathbb R$$ denote the Laplace transform of $\mu$. Assume $$\mu((-\infty,0))=0\tag1$$ and $$-\ln\mathcal L_\mu(t)=\alpha t+\int 1-e^{-tx}\:\nu({\rm d}x)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag2$$ for some $\alpha\ge0$ and some $\sigma$-finite measure $\nu$ on $[0,\infty)$ with $$\nu(\{0\})=0.\tag3$$

> I want to show that $$\alpha=\sup\left\{x\ge0:\mu([0,x))=0\right\}\tag4.$$

Intuitively, the claim shouldn't be hard to prove. And I think it's related to the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)#Definition) $\operatorname{supp}\mu$ of $\mu$. In the present context, this notion should reduce to $$\operatorname{supp}\mu=\left\{x\ge0:\mu((x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon))>0\text{ for all }\varepsilon>0\right\}\tag5.$$ Maybe we can show that the right-hand side of $(4)$ is equal to $\inf\operatorname{supp}$. However, even if it's possible to show that, I still wouldn't know how we can conclude $(4)$ from this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

$$\beta := \sup\{x \geq 0\::\: \mu([0,x))=0\},$$

then

$$\mathcal{L}_{\mu}(t) = \int_{[\beta,\infty)} e^{-tx} \, \mu(dx) = e^{-\beta t} \underbrace{\int_{[0,\infty)} e^{-tx} \, \tilde{\mu}(dx)}_{\mathcal{L}_{\tilde{\mu}}(t)} \tag{1}$$

for the shifted measure $\tilde{\mu}$ defined by $\tilde{\mu}(B) := \int 1_{B}(x-\beta)\, \mu(dx)=\mu(B+\beta)$. Note that, by construction, $\tilde{\mu}([0,x])>0$ for any $x>0$. Since $\tilde{\mu}$ is also a probability measure with $\tilde{\mu}(-\infty,0)=0$, its Laplace transform satisfies

$$- \ln \mathcal{L}_{\tilde{\mu}}(t) = \tilde{\alpha} t + \int (1-e^{-tx}) \tilde{\nu}(dx) \tag{2}$$ for some $\tilde{\alpha} \geq 0$ and some $\sigma$-finite measure $\tilde{\nu}$ on $[0,\infty)$. By $(1)$, we are done if we can show that $\tilde{\alpha}=0$. As $1-e^{-tx} \geq 0$, it follows from $(2)$ that

$$\mathcal{L}_{\tilde{\mu}}(t) \leq e^{-\tilde{\alpha} t}.$$

On the other hand, the monotonicity of the exponential function yields

$$\mathcal{L}_{\tilde{\mu}}(t) \geq \int_{[0,r]} \underbrace{e^{-tx}}_{\geq e^{-rt}} \, \tilde{\mu}(dx) \geq e^{-rt} \tilde{\mu}[0,r],$$

implying

$$\tilde{\mu}[0,r] e^{-rt} \leq e^{-\tilde{\alpha} t}$$ for all $t \geq 0$. If $\tilde{\mu}([0,r])>0$, then this gives $\tilde{\alpha} \leq r$. Recalling that $\tilde{\mu}([0,r])>0$ holds, by construction, for any $r>0$, we conclude that $\tilde{\alpha}=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think we need to rule out some border cases. Let $I:=\{x\ge0:\mu([0,x))=0\}$. If $I=\mathbb R$, we should have $1=\mu([0,\infty))\le\mu(\{0\})\le1$ and hence $\mu=\delta_0$ and $\beta=\delta_0$. On the other hand, if $I=\emptyset$, then $\beta=-\infty$ (and **I guess** we can show $\mu$ is strictly positive on any nontrivial interval). So, I guess we need to assume that $I\ne\emptyset$ and $I\ne\mathbb R$. Then $I$ is clearly bounded and I guess we can show that $I$ is closed (hence compact) and hence $\beta=\max I$. Right? How can we show the closedness?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Note that $I=\mathbb{R}$ cannot happen because $\mu$ is a probability measure. Moreover, $I=\emptyset$ cannot happen because $0 \in I$ is trivial.

Comment: $I=\mathbb R$ cannot happen, because I defined $I$ as a subset of $[0,\infty)$, but $I=[0,\infty)$ can happen if $\mu=\delta_0$ or am I missing something? And could you say something about my question on the closedness/compact of $I$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d If $\mu=\delta_0$, then $I=\{0\}$. What's exactly the problem about this case? Clearly, $\mu([0,x))>0$ for any $x>0$ and $\mu([0,0))=\mu(\emptyset)=0$. I don't see that the closedness/compactness is relevant for the question here. Since $I$ is a bounded set (again, because $\mu$ is a probability measure), compactness is  immediate from closedness. For closedness you have to use the contintuity of the measure $\mu$ from below and note that $x_n \uparrow x$ implies $[0,x_n) \uparrow [0,x)$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, in the case $\mu=\delta_0$ I thought it would be a problem that we consider intervals which don't contain the right endpoint. Regarding the closedness: What you write about the continuity of the measure is clear to me, but we need to consider arbitrary sequences $x_n\in I$ which converge to some $x\in\mathbb R$. Why is it no restriction to consider nondrecreasing sequences?

Comment: @0xbadf00d If, say, $x \in I$, then trivially $[0,x] \subseteq I$ by the monotonicity properties of the measure. Consequently, to check closedness we only need to check that the right-end point is also in $I$.

Comment: (a) Yeah, I guess we can simply replace $(x_n)_n$ by $y_n:=\max(x_1,\ldots,y_n)$ which still converges to $x$ is $(x_n)_n$ does. (b) Shouldn't it be $e^{\beta t}$ (instead of $e^{-\beta t}$) in $(1)$? We should have $\int_{[0,\:\infty)}\tilde\mu({\rm d}x)e^{-tx}=e^{-\beta t}\int_{[\beta,\:\infty)}\mu({\rm d}x)e^{-tx}$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d There was a typo in the definition of $\tilde{\mu}$; should be fine now.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the edit. Now how do you conclude the claim from $\tilde\alpha=0$? I'm only able to deduce $$(\alpha-\beta)t+\int1-e^{-tx}\:(\nu-\tilde\nu)({\rm d}x)=0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag3$$ from that. Did you differentiate $(3)$ wrt $t$? (BTW, I guess you've concluded the existence of $\tilde\alpha$ and $\tilde\nu$ from the Lévy-Khinchin formula, right?)

Comment: @0xbadf00d The point is that $\alpha$ and $\nu$ in the representation (2) (from your post) are unique. Since we know from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $$- \ln \mathcal{L}_{\mu}(t) = \beta t + \int (1-e^{-tx}) \tilde{\nu}(dx),$$ it follows that $\beta=\alpha$ and $\nu=\tilde{\nu}$.

Comment: (a) The uniqueness of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is part of the Lévy-Khinchin formula; but from your argumentation, it seems like this is somehow obvious. Why? (b) Do you know whether there are similar formulas for $(a,\sigma^2)$ in the canonical triple $(a,\sigma^2,\Pi)$ (as defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process#L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Khintchine_representation) for the general case of a measure on $\mathbb R$ (i.e. without the assumption $(1)$)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d (a) I don't know why you think that it "seems obvious" from my argumentation. My argumentation is, at that point of the proof based on the uniquess of the characteristics; if you know it from the Lévy-Khintchine formula, then fine. (b) No, I don't think so. For this reasoning to work it's crucial that $\mu$ is supported on $[0,\infty)$.